# Why am I not able to save / update data in wp_editor?

Tags: wp-editor

After looking at various suggestions here and on StackOverflow, I still can't figure out why my solution is not working.

I'm adding an extra `wp_editor`to my posts / pages, but the data is not saved / updated. What am I doing wrong?

```
class langauge{

    function __construct() {
        add_action('edit_form_after_editor', array($this, 'custom_meta_box_lang'));
        add_action('save_post', array($this, 'save_en_content'));
    }

    function custom_meta_box_lang(){
        global $post;
        // set 'your_meta_key' to the actual key
        $content = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_content_en', true);

        // only low case [a-z], no hyphens and underscores
        $editor = 'contenten';

        // See my comment below
        $editor_settings = array(
                                'wpautop'       =>      true,
                                'media_buttons' =>      true,
                                'textarea_name' =>      'content_en',
                                'textarea_rows' =>      10,
                                'drag_drop_upload' =>   true);

        wp_editor( stripslashes( $content ), $editor, $editor_settings);

    }

    function save_en_content($post_id){
        if(isset($_POST['content_en']) && $_POST['content_en'] != '')
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'content_en', $_POST['content_en']);
        else
            delete_post_meta($post_id, 'content_en');
    }


}

new langauge();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using :

```
// only low case [a-z], no hyphens and underscores
$editor = 'contenten';
```

and then trying to get it by different name:

```
  if(isset($_POST['content_en']) && $_POST['content_en'] != '')
```

another thing is u using different keys like @vancoder said

also remember to sanitize the data :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation

this code should work for u :

```
 function __construct() {
        add_action('edit_form_after_editor', array($this, 'custom_meta_box_lang'));
        add_action('save_post', array($this, 'save_en_content'));
    }

    function custom_meta_box_lang(){
        global $post;
        // set 'your_meta_key' to the actual key
        $content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'content_en', true);

        // only low case [a-z], no hyphens and underscores
        $editor = 'contenten';

        // See my comment below
        $editor_settings = array(
                                'wpautop'       =>      true,
                                'media_buttons' =>      true,
                                'textarea_name' =>      'content_en',
                                'textarea_rows' =>      10,
                                'drag_drop_upload' =>   true);

        wp_editor( stripslashes( $content ), $editor, $editor_settings);

    }

    function save_en_content($post_id){
        if(isset($_POST['contenten']) && $_POST['contenten'] != '')
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'content_en', $_POST['contenten']);
        else
            delete_post_meta($post_id, 'content_en');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably are saving it, but you're not loading it back into the editor afterwards. You're saving it as `content_en`, but you're attempting to get it back as `_content_en` - with an underscore.

You need to be consistent with the name.

The underscore prefix is used to hide custom meta from the default custom fields meta box.

Comment: Hi Vancoder, even if I do `'textarea_name' => '_content_en'` the content is not saved. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Update your code please

Comment: huh? Here? Doesn't matter. The data is not saved in DB. You can test it yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: I think I'll pass.